# Error while provisioning Active Directory account to user using access policy

Tags: java, active-directory, identity-management, oim

Hi I have OIM11gR2PS3 environment installed with Active Directory 11.1.6.0.0 Connector configured. We have password policy attached to AD resource.

Earlier users were having AD account provisioned. But from last couple of days on the basis of user creation in OIM AD account is not bale see in the account tab. I checked the access policy it's correctly configured. User also got correct role on basis of role membership.

I checked the oim-server1-dignostic.log file from OIM server, found below stack traces:

```
oracle.iam.platform.kernel.EventFailedException: An error occurred in oracle.iam.accesspolicy.impl.handlers.provisioning.ProvisionAccountActionHandler while provisioning resource 47,709 to user 13 and the cause of error is An error occurred in oracle.iam.provisioning.spi.DOBProvisioningMechanism/provision while provisioning application instance with key 0 to user with name 1161546 the cause of error is oracle.iam.provisioning.exception.GenericProvisioningException: DOBJ.USR_PASSWORD_DOES_NOT_MATCH_POLICY: H: Password Does Not Satisfy Policy: Max. Number of unicode characters=0 : Max. Number of unicode characters=0..
    at oracle.iam.accesspolicy.impl.util.AccessPolicyUtil.createEventFailedException(AccessPolicyUtil.java:289)
    at oracle.iam.accesspolicy.impl.handlers.provisioning.ProvisionAccountActionHandler.execute(ProvisionAccountActionHandler.java:167)
    at oracle.iam.accesspolicy.impl.handlers.provisioning.ProvisionAccountActionHandler.execute(ProvisionAccountActionHandler.java:70)
    at oracle.iam.platform.kernel.impl.OIMEvent.executeHandlers(OIMEvent.java:214)
    at oracle.iam.platform.kernel.impl.MonitoredOIMEvent.invokeExecuteHandler(MonitoredOIMEvent.java:99)
    at oracle.iam.platform.kernel.impl.MonitoredOIMEvent.executeHandlers(MonitoredOIMEvent.java:69)
    at oracle.iam.platform.kernel.impl.OIMEvent.execute(OIMEvent.java:157)
    at oracle.iam.platform.kernel.impl.ProcessImpl.executeStage(ProcessImpl.java:223)
    at oracle.iam.platform.kernel.impl.OIMProcess.doStageExecution(OIMProcess.java:62)
    at oracle.iam.platform.kernel.impl.ProcessImpl.execute(ProcessImpl.java:182)
    at oracle.iam.platform.kernel.impl.MonitoredOIMProcess.execute(MonitoredOIMProcess.java:33)
    at oracle.iam.platform.kernel.impl.Utils.manageSyncProcessing(Utils.java:73)
    at oracle.iam.platform.kernel.impl.OrchestrationAsyncTask$2.execute(OrchestrationAsyncTask.java:101)
    at oracle.iam.platform.kernel.impl.Utils.executeInContext(Utils.java:60)
at oracle.iam.platform.kernel.impl.Utils.executeInContext(Utils.java:46)
    at oracle.iam.platform.kernel.impl.OrchestrationAsyncTask.executeInOrchContext(OrchestrationAsyncTask.java:97)
    at oracle.iam.platform.kernel.impl.OrchestrationAsyncTask.execute(OrchestrationAsyncTask.java:74)
    at oracle.iam.platform.async.impl.TaskExecutor.executeUnmanagedTask(TaskExecutor.java:99)
    at oracle.iam.platform.async.impl.TaskExecutor.execute(TaskExecutor.java:69)
    at oracle.iam.platform.async.messaging.MessageReceiver.onMessage(MessageReceiver.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3329.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:310)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy647.onMessage(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.MDListener.execute(MDListener.java:583)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.MDListener.transactionalOnMessage(MDListener.java:486)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.MDListener.onMessage(MDListener.java:388)
    at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.onMessage(JMSSession.java:4817)
    at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.execute(JMSSession.java:4491)
    at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.executeMessage(JMSSession.java:3945)
    at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.access$000(JMSSession.java:115)
    at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession$UseForRunnable.run(JMSSession.java:5337)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:550)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:263)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
    Caused by: oracle.iam.provisioning.exception.GenericProvisioningException: An error occurred in oracle.iam.provisioning.spi.DOBProvisioningMechanism/provision while provisioning application instance with key 0 to user with name 1161546 the cause of error is oracle.iam.provisioning.exception.GenericProvisioningException: DOBJ.USR_PASSWORD_DOES_NOT_MATCH_POLICY: H: Password Does Not Satisfy Policy: Max. Number of unicode characters=0 : Max. Number of unicode characters=0.
    at oracle.iam.provisioning.util.ProvisioningUtil.throwGenericProvisioningException(ProvisioningUtil.java:258)
    at oracle.iam.provisioning.spi.DOBProvisioningMechanism.provision(DOBProvisioningMechanism.java:548)
    at oracle.iam.provisioning.impl.ProvisioningServiceImpl.provision(ProvisioningServiceImpl.java:547)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3355.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
    at oracle.iam.platform.utils.DMSMethodInterceptor.invoke(DMSMethodInterceptor.java:35)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy609.provision(Unknown Source)at oracle.iam.accesspolicy.impl.handlers.provisioning.ProvisionAccountActionHandler.execute(ProvisionAccountActionHandler.java:164)
    ... 42 more
```

Any help at earliest would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is due to password policy which is attached to the AD resource. There is password policy configuration where someone modified **Max Number of unicode characters** to 0. Due to which the AD provisioning failed as system not able to validate the password of user against password policy.

I have changed the Max Number of unicode characters set to blank. When tried to provision the AD account to user it went successfully.

Thanks